# How to get page index in ViewPager after swiping?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, swipe, ontouchlistener

I've a problem which is I have a viewpager, and I've made a GestureDetector for TouchListener to detect swipes..
I made when user swipes right or left, it increments or decrements an array which have key for every Image according to it's index, so that I can check if this picture is Favorited before or to be able to Download it..etc, it works fine when User swipe smoothly left or right, but the problem is when User swipes fast several times the increment and decrement results incorrect index, so how can I handle such a problem, any ideas?

This is code that extends SimpleOnGestureListener:

```
      @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
```

This is the code when swipe right, and same on swipe left except it increments "pagerPosition" not decrements:

```
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                pagerPosition--;

               boolean isFavorites = db.checkfavorites(imageUrls[pagerPosition]);
               if(isFavorites){
                      fave.setVisible(true);
                      unfave.setVisible(false);
               }else{
                      fave.setVisible(false);
                      unfave.setVisible(true);     
               }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `ViewPager` why not use `OnPageChangeListener`it gives you the position of the current page, you could perform your calculations based on that.